# How to change default window manager in ubuntu to enlightenment

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager

I'm using Wubi Ubuntu and I am trying to change the window manager to enlightenment.  I've been googling for a while now with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have the enlightenment window manager installed.  On ubuntu the package is e16.  Then, before logging in change your session:

[image: Ubuntu session]

All your available window managers should be listed.  Pick one and log in.

Comment: This changes the session desktop environment. There's also the possibility of one wanting to keep running Gnome and just replace `metacity` with e.g. `xfwm4`.

Answer (score 2):

The website [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/kde) has a great tutorial on how to set up different managers in Ubuntu.  They focus on KDE, but like the tutorial says, it's easy to apply to others like xfce.